# Length of the data to Encrypt is invalid

Tags: c#

Getting Exception " length of the data to ENCRYPTION is invalid".

```
private static readonly byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("S@sh@kt@ VMS");

public static string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, string encryptionPassword)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    try
    {
        var algorithm = GetAlgorithm(encryptionPassword);
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
        {
            byte[] bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
            encryptedBytes = InMemoryCrypt(bytesToEncrypt, encryptor);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}

 // Performs an in-memory encrypt/decrypt transformation on a byte array.

private static byte[] InMemoryCrypt(byte[] data, ICryptoTransform transform)
{
    MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (Stream stream = new CryptoStream(memory, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        //stream.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
    return memory.ToArray();
}

private static RijndaelManaged GetAlgorithm(string encryptionPassword)
{
    // Create an encryption key from the encryptionPassword and salt.
    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionPassword, salt);
    // Declare that we are going to use the Rijndael algorithm with the key that we've just got.
    var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
    int bytesForKey = algorithm.KeySize/8;
    int bytesForIV = algorithm.BlockSize/8;
    algorithm.Key = key.GetBytes(bytesForKey);
    algorithm.IV = key.GetBytes(bytesForIV);
    return algorithm;
}
```

And the decryption routine is:

```
public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string encryptionPassword)
{
    var algorithm = GetAlgorithm(encryptionPassword);
    algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 
    byte[] descryptedBytes;
    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        descryptedBytes = InMemoryCrypt(encryptedBytes, decryptor);
    } 
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(descryptedBytes); 
}
```

Comment: In what line? What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Comment: `PaddingMode.None` requires that the input is a multiple of the block size

Comment: BTW. a constant is not a good salt.

Comment: Thnx that Works BUTTTTTT Now Error:  it is Padding does not work and cannot be removed"

Comment: I have used  PaddingMode.ISO10126

Answer (score 6):

`PaddingMode.None` requires that the input is a multiple of the block size. Use somethink like `PaddingMode.PKCS7` instread.

---

A few other issues with your code:

1. A constant doesn't make a good salt
2. The constant salt together with deterministic derivation of the IV from the password means that you're reusing (Key, IV) pairs, which should not be done
3. You don't add authentication/some kind of MAC. That often leads to padding oracles or similar attacks
4. You read more the native size from the PBKDF2 output. That halves your key derivation speed without slowing down an attacker.

Comment: Got bug --->>> "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." When decrpted

Comment: @Aditya When I replace `None` with `PKCS7` the code runs the encryption without exception. Since you didn't post your decryption code, I can't help you with that.

Comment: public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string encryptionPassword)
        {
            var algorithm = GetAlgorithm(encryptionPassword);
            algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] descryptedBytes;
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
            {
                byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
                descryptedBytes = InMemoryCrypt(encryptedBytes, decryptor);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(descryptedBytes);
        }